# System.getProperty(param) returns wrong value - Android

Tags: java, android, shell

steps I do:

I do in code

```
System.setProperty("myproperty", 1);
```

and then I set in a shell script the property "myProperty" to 3.
like this:

```
# setprop "myproperty" 3
```

and then in the code I try to read the property like this:

```
System.getProperty("myproperty");
```

I get the value of 1. which means that the set from the shell didn't actually work.
but when I print all props from shell with

```
# getprop
```

I see in the list that myproperty equals 3.

in shorter words: I want to change the value of a property from a script, and I see that this scripts actually changes the property but in the java code I get the old value.

any ideas?

Comment: `System.getProperty("myProperty")` is different than `System.getProperty("myproperty")`.

Comment: @kocko this is not the problem, I just mistyped it here.

Comment: @LeeMeador I'm talking android

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Java code in Android provides System.getProperty and System.setProperty functions in java library but it's important to note that although these java APIs are semantically equal to native version, java version store data in a totally different place. Actually, a hashtable is employed by dalvik VM to store properties. So, java properties are separated, it can't get or set native properties, and neither vice versa.

You can use android.os.SystemProperties class can manipulate native properties, though it's intended for internal usage only. It calls through jni into native property library to get/set properties.

Comment: I work in the /android/framework/base so this is not a problem, I can use this class in there. thank you for the help.

Answer (score 5):

getprop/setprop work on `android.os.SystemProperties`, not on `java.lang.System`.

Unfortunately, this class is not available to third party application. Apparently you have rooted your device, so you may still access it.

Comment: All you need is Java reflexion, root is not needed to use this class. Still works on Lollipop too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use that snippet to run `getProp` as shell command and get the value of any property:

```
private String getSystemProperty(String propertyName) {
    String propertyValue = "[UNKNOWN]";

    try {
        Process getPropProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop " + propertyName);

        BufferedReader osRes =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getPropProcess.getInputStream()));

        propertyValue = osRes.readLine();

        osRes.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Do nothing - can't get property value
    }

    return propertyValue;
}
```